# Which of the following values are needed for $5^{166} \mod 41$ using fast exponentiation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Which of the following values are needed for computing $5^{166} \mod 41$ using fast exponentiation.

The values given are : 
$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
 & \text{$5^{2^i} \pmod {41}$} \\ \hline
\text{ 1} & 5  \\ \hline
\text{2} & 25  \\ \hline
\text{3} & 10  \\ \hline
\text{4} & 18  \\ \hline
\text{5} & 37  \\ \hline
\text{6} & 30  \\ \hline
\text{7} & 9  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the table:

$i=1\rightarrow5^{10_2}\equiv5(\mod 41)\\
i=2\rightarrow5^{100_2}\equiv25(\mod 41)\\
i=3\rightarrow5^{1000_2}\equiv10(\mod 41)\\
i=4\rightarrow5^{10000_2}\equiv18(\mod 41)\\
i=5\rightarrow5^{100000_2}\equiv37(\mod 41)\\
i=6\rightarrow5^{1000000_2}\equiv30(\mod 41)\\
i=7\rightarrow5^{10000000_2}\equiv9(\mod 41)$

Now let's turn $166$ into its binary form: $10100110_2$. So, $5^{166}=5^{10100110_2}$ Consider that for $i=k$, $5^{2^k}$ is used if the $(8-k)^{\text{th}}$ bit of $10100110_2$ is $1$ (Example: $5^{2^4}$ is used if the $4$th bit is $1$, which it's not). So, the ones which are used are number $1,2,5,7$.